# How do I open a copied project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I have copied a whole project onto my PC, both into My Documents/Visual Studio and into inetpub/wwwroot, but when I try to open the project in Visual Studio, it tries to open just 1 file .vssproj and gives me error messages, like : "The project file cannot be loaded. The application for project ... is not installed.". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "The project file cannot be loaded. The application for project ... is not installed."

Comment: Yes, I have considered marking it as answered. However, although I gave points for the below answers, nevertheless they are not really what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same exact error when double-clicking on the file as opposed to *going to VS and using its menu to open it*. It seems a problem with file associations.

Answer (score 2):

If VS 2005 has not been upgraded to Service Pack 1 then a web application project (rather than a website) will give this error.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, without knowing a specific error it's hard to help. However, the sln and csproj files are just text files, you can always just open them up in notepad and do a search and replace on any obvious path problems. It's often quicker than creating a new project and adding all the files / references.

Comment: "The project file cannot be loaded.
The application for project...is not installed.
"

Answer (score 0):

Without telling the specific error you're getting it's hard to help, but I'm guessing the file paths in the project file are incorrect. Try creating a new project and manually adding the files and see if you get the same errors.

Comment: "The project file cannot be loaded.
The application for project...is not installed.
"

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific error messages, it's tough to be sure, but if you have an entire solution from your source machine rather than just a single project, you may want to try copying that over instead.

Comment: "The project file cannot be loaded.
The application for project...is not installed.
"